# GWT Editor Framework ListEditor

Tags: gwt, editor, requestfactory

I cant get a idea of why this doesn't work well.

First. My behavior is something like this, i'll omit code to try explain better:

```
public class ProgramaEditor extends Composite implements Editor<ProgramaProxy> {
  /*edits a ProgramaProxy just fine*/         
  /* a EditorList to edit BitacoraProxy */
  @UiField BitacoraListEditor bitacoras;

 }

    public class BitacoraListEditor extends Composite implements IsEditor<ListEditor<BitacoraProxy, BitacoraEditor>>, HasRequestContext<List<BitacoraProxy>>{
 /* edit a list of BitacoraProxy just fine */
 protected class BitacoraEditorSource extends EditorSource<BitacoraEditor>{
      /* the editor source that vends Editors of BitacoraProxy*/
      public BitacoraEditor create(int index) {
              final BitacoraEditor editor = new BitacoraEditor();
                      editor.setIndex(index);

                 /*more code*/

                       editor.addDeleteEditorHanlder(new EditorDeleteHandler() {
                        /* ... handler to remove a Editor from the list */
                        subeditors.getList().remove(event.getIndex());
                       }
      }
  }

 private ListEditor<BitacoraProxy, BitacoraEditor> subeditors = ListEditor.of(new BitacoraEditorSource());
 }
```

On the server side:

```
 @Entity
 public class Bitacora extends EntityBase {
     @NotNull(message="La fecha no puede ser nulo")
     private Date fecha;    
 }
```

So all works well in the normal workflow Edit ProgramaProxy then add BitacoraProxys and then Save, i can save ProgramaProxy and its @OneToMany BitacoraProxy with the ListEditor.

The problem is when i remove a BitacoraProxy from the EditorList with:

```
  subeditors.getList().remove(event.getIndex());
   /*Please note the  @NotNull on the Many side on the property fecha.*/
```

When i save the whole object i get constrait violations of the property:

```
  @NotNull(message="La fecha no puede ser nulo")
  private Date fecha;
```

Why? I just debugued my code and the ListEditor its in sync i mean:

```
Add a BitacoraProxy -> ListEditor.getList() - size = 1
Then I remove a BitacoraProxy from the ListEditor.getList() - size = 0
```

No BitacoraProxy on the ListEditor getList(), then on the Save button:

```
 driver.flush().fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void response) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onConstraintViolation(Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations) {
                DialogHandler handler = DialogHandler.getInstance();
                ErrorDialog errDlg = handler.createErrorDialog();               

                for(ConstraintViolation<?> violation:violations){
                    errDlg.addDetail(violation.getMessage());
                }
                /* more code */
        });
```

Why i'am geting constraint violations of Proxys that doesn't exist on the ListEditor.getList().

Any help would be apreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `BitacoraProxy` has been `edit()`ed (by the Editor framework at least), so it's part of the `RequestContext`, and will be sent to the server (it's ID only, unless you changed some of its properties), and will therefore be validated, whether it'll be used later or not.

This is a known issue (1), but was part of the original design of RequestFactory so I'm not sure how to really *fix* it. See also [issue 5926](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5926).

---

(1) see the TODO at http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1601806/diff/9001/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/impl/AbstractRequestContext.java#newcode1182

Comment: Hi thomas, thank you for your answer. On ListEditor(CompositeEditor) when remove from a list, maybe there need to be something that tells the RequestContext remove that EntityProxy?. I just removed the @NotNull and then validate my field on the client side.